# Convert a number to binary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Given a non-negative integer n, write a function to_binary/ToBinary which returns that number in a binary format.

This is my code but some tests don't pass.
I appreciate it if  you help me fix my code:

```
def to_binary(n):
     string = ""
     if n > 2:
        string = string + str(n % 2)
        x = n // 2
        while  x >= 2:
            i = x % 2
            string = string + str(i)
            x = x // 2
         
        string = string + str(1)
        l = len(string)   
        string[l::-1]
        return int(string)
           
     else:
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        if n == 2:
            return 10
```

Comment: btw, the line `string[l::-1]` does not change variable `string` content

Comment: oh , thank you. You are right! that was the problem! I don't know how I added that one! It was fixed

Comment: Why are you returning an int? Shouldn't it be a string?

Answer (score 1):

Few points to note.

1. Changing the concatenation logic will generate the string in reverse. You won't have to reverse it in the end.

```py
In [10]: s = ''

In [11]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     s = s + str(i)
    ...:

In [12]: s
Out[12]: '01234'
```

```
In [13]: s = ''

In [14]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     s = str(i) + s  # add the existing string after i
    ...:

In [15]: s
Out[15]: '43210'
```

2. You don't require a different logic for numbers less than 2. You shouldn't have to hardcode anything unless you're using recursion. In which case, hardcoding is simply the base case.
3. You are not reversing the string at all.

```
s[::-1]
```

This does not reverse a string in-place. Strings in python are immutable. What you can do is,

```
s = s[::-1]
```

4. Not providing the limits in a slice syntax is the same as providing start and end values (0 and length). You don't have to explicitly write `s[len(s)::-1]`.
5. Your logic is almost correct. Just remove everything and keep the while loop and the code will work.

```
def to_bin(x):
    if x == 0:
        return '0'
    b = ''
    while x > 0:
        b = str(x%2) + b
        x //= 2
    return b
```

6. There are of course several ways to do this without writing code just by using the builtin features of python.

Comment: Only relevant (and very good) answer here... +1

Comment: @Tomerikoo I did have the urge to ask him to do his own homework though 

Answer (score 0):

You could try the implementing the mathematical method of converting bases into Python. Every number can be expressed as the sum of the powers of a base. For binary, base 2, this would be `N*2**n + ... + A*2**3 + B*2**2 + C*2**1 + D*2**0`. The hardest part is finding `N`, but from there we can use `divmod` to solve for the other variables.

```py
def get_highest_power(num, base=2):
    n = 0
    while True:
        if base**(n+1) >= num:
            break
        n += 1
    return n

def solve_for_coefficients(num, power, base=2):
    coefficients = []
    for p in range(power, -1, -1):
        coef, num = divmod(num, base**p)
        coefficients.append(coef)
    return coefficients

leading_power = get_highest_power(1000)
coefficients = solve_for_coefficients(1000, leading_power)
```

In order to get the base conversion, just use something like `int(''.join([str(i) for i in coefficients]))`. This method works for all bases less than 10, since bases after ten require letters (but then again, you could use look at the items in `coefficients` to get the letters).

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to solve the problem "number to binary string", you could use simple python:

```
def to_binary(n):
    return "{:b}".format(n)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's not allowed to use these. Of course there is also `bin(...)`. This is probably an assignment.

Comment: @tcarreira you already found the problem ,why not post an answer according to that? (`string[l::-1]`)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use bin() instead.

```
def to_binary(n):
  return(bin(n)[2:])


to_binary(6)
'110'
```

Comment: See comments on the other answers... I think it is quite obvious that the OP is trying to implement that themselves...

Comment: You may be right, but it wasn't really clearly stated.

Comment: @D.Lohrsträter In the comments of tcarreira's post, the OP said they cannot use the `bin` method.